# Next js HTML not loading in css

Tags: css, next.js

I am using Nextjs and loading flaticon css in _app.js like:

`import '../public/assets/css/flaticon.css';`

In following content I am getting error:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Flaticon';
  src: url('../fonts/Flaticon.eot');
  src: url('../fonts/Flaticond41d.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('../fonts/Flaticon.woff') format('woff'),
    url('../fonts/Flaticon.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('../fonts/Flaticon.html#Flaticon') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Following error I am getting:

```
error - ./public/assets/css/Flaticon.html
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> <!DOCTYPE html>
| <html lang="en-US" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">
|   <head>
```

Comment: Remove ` url('../fonts/Flaticon.html#Flaticon') format('svg');` line and see if its working. If its working it could be due the nextjs loader issue. You need to set corresponding loader (html) in `next.config.js`

Comment: Yes it's working after removing `url('../fonts/Flaticon.html#Flaticon') format('svg');` @kiranvj How do we set loader for this file?

Comment: I havent used it but try these links https://github.com/alexblunck/next-html , https://webpack.js.org/loaders/html-loader/  and https://dev.to/marcinwosinek/adding-webpack-loader-to-next-js-application-1c7e

Comment: I am not able to figure out how to add this loader.

Comment: @kiranvj thanks your suggestion worked. Posted correct steps in answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solve this by following steps:

1. Install html loader

`npm install --save-dev html-loader`

2. Add this in next.config.js file

```
webpack: (config, options) => {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.html$/i,
      use: 'html-loader',
    });

    return config
  }
```

Reference: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/custom-webpack-config

Comment: Anyone doing this make sure to restart dev server to reflect changes in `next.config.js`